# Problem in the table for the case where there is not exist

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

For different values of time and force in the *At* formula, I have a problem with the first case, which requires the first *At*, and I can not fix it.

Also, how can I make the *data* table without manually typing the values for the *time* and *forc* lists? I want a table from 1 to *n* with *At*, *time*, and *forc*. Here is my code.

```
m = 1266.5;
k = 50;
Pt = {
    {0, 0},
    {.2, 1000},
    {.4, 0},
    {.6, -1000},
    {.8, 0}
   };
ListLinePlot[Pt];
ω =  N[Sqrt[(k*1000)/m], 5];
Round[T = (2*N[Pi, 5])/ω, 0.1];
Δt = Round[T/10, 0.1]
time = NestList[# + Δt &, Part[Pt, 1, 1], 
  Round[FixedPoint[(#) &, (Part[Pt, 5, 1]/Δt)]]]
forc = Table[p1 = Interpolation[Pt, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 
  P1 = p1[time[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@time - 1}]
At = Table[
  At[[i - 1]] + 
   1/ω*(time[[i]] - (forc[[i]] - forc[[i - 1]])/(
       time[[i]] - time[[i - 1]])*
       time[[i - 1]])*(Sin[ω*time[[i]]] - 
      Sin[ω*time[[i - 1]]]) + 
   1/ω^2*(forc[[i]] - forc[[i - 1]])/(
    time[[i]] - 
     time[[i - 1]])*(Cos[ω*time[[i]]] - 
      Cos[ω*
        time[[i - 1]]] + ω*(time[[i]]*Sin[ω*time[[i]]] -
          time[[i - 1]]*Sin[ω*time[[i - 1]]]))
  , {i, 1, Length@time - 1}]

data = {{{Subscript[t, i], s}, {Subscript[p, i], N}}, {Part[time, 1], 
    Part[forc, 1]}, {Part[time, 2], Part[forc, 2]}, {Part[time, 3], 
    Part[forc, 3]}, {Part[time, 4], Part[forc, 4]}, {Part[time, 5], 
    Part[forc, 5]}, {Part[time, 6], Part[forc, 6]}, {Part[time, 7], 
    Part[forc, 7]}, {Part[time, 8], Part[forc, 8]}};
Grid[data, Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text", Background -> {{Gray, None}, {LightGray, None}}]
```

The result is like this:

```
Hold[{Symbol + 0.159154 (0. - List) (0. - Sin[6.28322 List]) - (
   0.02533 (0. - List) (1. - Cos[6.28322 List] + 
      6.28322 (0. - List Sin[6.28322 List])))/List, 22.5955 + At[[1]],
   12.3684 + At[[2]], 2.59249 + At[[3]], 16.5284 + At[[4]], 
  24.1416 + At[[5]], 22.5298 + At[[6]], -12.3969 + At[[7]]}]
```

Comment: I think you're trying to find values of `At` such that `At[[i + 1]]` is a function of `At[[i]]`, time and force. You might use `At = ConstantArray[0, Length@time];`  then set `At[[1]]` to its value at `time[[1]]`. The `Table` for *At* needs to be corrected to fix indexing for the `forc` and `time` lists (for example, `time[[i - 1]]` is incorrect when *i* is 1).

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem with *At* is that lists in Mathematica start at index 1, not 0. The `Table` for *At* begins at `i = 1`, but uses `forc[[i - 1]]` and `time[[i - 1]]`. When *i* is 1, `forc[[0]]` and `time[[0]]` are incorrect, and that's the reason that the result has `Hold`..., etc.

The *data* table is easier to fix so that you don’t need to manually type the values for the *time* and *forc* lists. The `time` list is longer than the `forc` list, so drop the last time value from `data`. `Transpose` arranges the `time` and `forc` lists into an array. `Sequence` connects the array with the column titles.

```
data = {{{Subscript[t, i], "s"}, {Subscript[p, i],"N"}},
  Sequence@@Transpose[{time[[;; Length@forc]], forc}]};
```

**Other comments**

I don't understand why you compute force as a function of time with `Length@time - 1`. This means that the `time` list is longer than the `forc` list, and that causes problems when you compute *At* and the *data* table. You don't need `forc = Table[`... to compute force. Use this instead to get the same results:

```
p1 = Interpolation[Pt, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
forc = p1/@Most@time;
```

There's a simpler way to compute the times without `NestWhile` and `FixedPoint`. Use `Pt[[-1, 1]]` to get the last value of the *Pt* list, so if you change *Pt*, the times will always use the last value of *Pt*. Be very careful using single uppercase letters like `T` for symbols. Mathematica has special meanings for some of of them (`N` is an example). It’s better to use lowercase for single-letter symbols.

```
ω = N[Sqrt[(k*1000)/m], 5];
t = 2*Pi/ω;
Δt = Round[t/10, 0.1];
time = Table[i, {i, Pt[[1, 1]], Pt[[-1, 1]], Δt}]
```

You can use `Part` in statements like `Part[Pt, 1, 1]`, but `Pt[[1, 1]]` does the same thing and it saves some typing.